# Angular $http.get losing decimals when parsing response to json object

Tags: json, angularjs, http, parsing, get

I'm using $http.get to make a request to an API which return this message:

```
{code":0,"message":"OK","return":{"exchangeRate":**1.0000000**,"oAmmount":**100.00**,"dAmmount":**100.00**,"tokenRequired":{"email":false,"physicalToken":false,"sms":false}}}
```

As you see this is a well formed JSON. When the $http.get fires the success the object injected as a parameter to the function loses the decimal places for the exchangeRate, oAmmount and dAmmount.

```
$http.get(url, SERVICE_CONFIG.config)
                    .success(function(data) {
                        //My Stuff
                    })
```

I've tried passing in the config object the following object `{timeout: 20000, responseType: "json"}`

When debugging the app I see the data object as `{exchangeRate: **1**, oAmmount: **100**, dAmmount: **100**, tokenRequired: ...}`

Any idea why I'm loosing the decimal places on the floats?

Thnx!

Comment: JSON is stripped down to the minimum amount of data for efficiency. Non-significant decimals in a number are usually not needed for anything so they get stripped out.
If you want to retain the decimals you'll have to send the number as a string, or else add an extra property to declare how many decimals you want.

Comment: In fact, for the same reason JSON doesn't care about non-significant figures, neither do floats. You'll have to read up on the IEEE floating point spec for an explanation, but it's basically done for efficiency. Better to be able to represent very large values than to store the number of sigfigs as well as a decimal place. That would cripple the potential of floating points.